# DataGrid проблемы с вертикальной прокруткой

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Добрый день, столкнулся с проблемой стандартного поведения `ScrollViewer`'a в `DataGrid`. В моей таблице одна строка может занимать достаточно большой размер по высоте из-за деталей строки. Когда записей больше одной проблем никаких нет, `ScrollViewer` нормально отрабатывает и вертикальный скролл работает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но как только в `DataGrid`е только одна запись... `ScrollViewer` перестает работать: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В результате если эта строка будет больше `DataGrid`'a то она просто выйдет за пределы видимости.
Я пробовал использовать пустой `DataGrid` без стилей, результат аналогичен.

Вопрос: Можно ли как-то изменить поведение `DataGrid`'a?

Comment: Может можно обойтись заданием минимальной высоты DataGrid?

Comment: @S.Kost боюсь проблема вылезает из-за встроенного в RowDetails встроенного `DataGrid` который тоже может быть довольно большим. Поэтому такой вариант не подойдет.